# is it possible to use Gson.fromJson() to get ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, gson

let's say i have a `json` array of arrays

```
String jsonString = [["John","25"],["Peter","37"]];
```

i would like to parst this into `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` objects. when i used

`Gson.fromJson(jsonString,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>.class)`

it doesn't seem to work and i did a work around by using

`Gson.fromJson(jsonString,String[][].class)`

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, use a [`TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html).

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>() {}.getType());
```

The `TypeToken` allows you to specify the generic type you actually want, which helps Gson find the types to use during deserialization.

It uses this gem: [`Class#getGenericSuperClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass%28%29). The fact that it is an anonymous class makes it a sub class of `TypeToken<...>`. It's equivalent to a class like

```
class Anonymous extends TypeToken<...>
```

The specification of the method states that

> If the superclass is a parameterized type, the `Type` object returned must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source code.

If you specified

```
new TypeToken<String>(){}.getType();
```

the `Type` object returned would actually be a `ParameterizedType` on which you can retrieve the actual type arguments with [`ParameterizedType#getActualTypeArguments()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29).

The type argument would be the `Type` object for `java.lang.String` in the example above. In your example, it would be a corresponding `Type` object for `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. Gson would keep going down the chain until it built the full map of types it needs.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.. :) works like a charm..
May i know how this TypeToken gets the bounded type? i just inferred that this would be gone because of the type erasure..

Comment: @BlackPanther It uses this gem: [`Class#getGenericSuperClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass()). The fact that it is an anonymous class makes it a sub class of `TypeToken<...>`. It's equivalent to `class Anonymous extends TypeToken<...>`. The specification of the method states that `If the superclass is a parameterized type, the Type object returned must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source code.`

Comment: @BlackPanther It's an old hack. [This](http://gafter.blogspot.ca/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) should explain it further.

Comment: wow.. excellent design.. thank you so much for the info... maybe you should make it part of the answer so that others may learn the actual implementation..

Comment: i understood the point you were refering... in order to call the `getGenericSuperClass` method this class has to be subclassed. god i was dumb..!! thx again...:)

Comment: can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280055/how-does-the-method-infer-the-type-of-t/22290104#22290104) question and help me..?