# How do I deserialize an object with a generic type?

Tags: java, json, generics, gson, json-deserialization

```
public class ResponseData<T>
{
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String mStatus;
    @SerializedName("description")
    private String mDescription;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private ArrayList<T> mData;
    @SerializedName("error_code")
    private int mErrorCode;

    public String getStatus() {return mStatus;}
    public String getDescription() { return mDescription;}
    public ArrayList<T> getData() { return mData; }
}
```

//common fields go here

```
public class BaseData {}
```

//user feilds go here

```
public class UserData extends BaseData {}
```

//some location fields go here

```
public class LocationData extends BaseData {}
```

//Json Deserializer

```
public class JsonDeserializer
{
    public static String toJson(Object t)
    {
        return new Gson().toJson(t);
    }

    public static <T> T fromInputStream(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> clz)
    {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        return new Gson().fromJson(reader, clz);
    }
}


public class HttpRequester
{
    public enum RequestType {GET, POST, DELETE, PUT};

    public void makeRequest(RequestType requestType, BaseData baseData, String path)
    {

        //submit data to api
        //the api then returns a response
        // baseData.getClass(); //this can either be UserData or LocationData

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        //I am getting stuck here. I want the responseData mData field to be the same type as the baseData I am sending to the api.

        //this is not valid syntax
        ResponseData response = JsonDeserializer.fromInputStream(entity.getContent(), ResponseData<baseData.getClass()>.class );

    }
}
```

Here is some sample json

```
{"data":[{"username":"james","email":"james@gmail.com","height":72.0,"phone":"+15555555555"}], "error_code": 0, "description":null }

{"data":[{"latidue":40.022022,"longitude":-29.23939, "street":"union ave", "borough":"manhattan"}', "error_code": 0, "description":null }
```

The JsonDeserializer should return either ResponseData with mData being an arraylist of type LocationData or ResponseData with mData being an arrayList of of type UserData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [don't use raw types.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Second, You'll need to use type tokens. A `TypeToken` is a pseudo-hack to get around some of the limitations of type erasure.

You'll need to create a type token

```
TypeToken token = new TypeToken<ResponseDate<LocationData>>() {};
```

And then feed the `TypeToken`'s represented type to Gson (don't recreate a new `Gson` object every time, save and use the one instance)

```
gson.fromGson(reader, token.getType());
```

You'll need to have a `TypeToken` for each parametrized version of `ResponseData<..>`.

Related:

- [is it possible to use Gson.fromJson() to get ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271779/is-it-possible-to-use-gson-fromjson-to-get-arraylistarrayliststring/22271806#22271806)
- [Gson TypeToken with dynamic ArrayList item type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylist-item-type/20803111#20803111)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I knew I had to use TypeToken the only problem was I trying to figure out how to get the type token on during runtime. I was able to solve by using the factory pattern. The ResponseData could either be location or user data. So I created a token factory that returns either a new TypeToken<ResponseDate<LocationData>>() {}; or new TypeToken<ResponseDate<UserData>>() {}; and passed it to the JsonDeserializer.fromInputStream