# Cannot resolve generic parameter TypeToken from Guava

Tags: java, generics, guava

I am developing a framework for building generified menus for a Selenium testing framework, and I've been using Guava TypeToken to resolve the types of generic parameters, but now I've run into a problem where the type token doesn't resolve a parameter:

I have an `abstract` base `class` for a builder that generates a menu option:

```
public abstract class AbstractMenuOptionBuilder<O extends IClickable>  {

    protected final TypeToken<AbstractMenuOptionBuilder<O>> typeToken = new
            TypeToken<AbstractMenuOptionBuilder<O>>(getClass()) { };

    public abstract O create();
}
```

This is a concrete `class` for a builder:

```
public class MenuOptionBuilder<O extends IClickable> extends AbstractMenuOptionBuilder<O> {

    public O create() {
        TypeToken<?> genericOptionParam = typeToken.resolveType(AbstractMenuOptionBuilder.class.getTypeParameters()[0]);

        Class<O> optionClass;

        try {

            optionClass = (Class<O>) Class.forName(genericOptionParam.getType().getTypeName());

             <.... snip ....>

        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.catching(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have an `abstract` base `class` for menus which has a method to return a list of menu options:

```
public abstract class AbstractMenu<O extends IClickable> {

    public final List<O> getOptions() {

        //This is where my plan doesn't work. The runtime type is given by
        //a concrete menu class which extends AbstractMenu, but that runtime
        //type doesn't seem to pass through to the abstract base class for the builder.
        MenuOptionBuilder<O> builder = new MenuOptionBuilder<O>(new MenuOptionBean()){};

             <.... snip ....>
    }

}
```

And I have a concrete menu `class` that `extends` it:

```
   //The runtime type of 'Link' is not known by the type token that is supposed to
   //resolve it in the abstract builder base class.
   public SimpleMenu extends AbstractMenu<Link> {
       <.... snip ....>
   }
```

I was expected that the variable `genericOptionParam` in `MenuOptionBuilder` would resolve to `Link`, but it doesn't Instead, it resolved to `O`, the name of the generic type parameter instead of its runtime type of `Link`. If I create an additional base `class` like this, the generic parameter resolves correctly:

```
public abstract class AbstractSimpleLinkedMenu extends AbstractMenu<Link> {

    public final List<Link> getOptions() {

        MenuOptionBuilder<Link> builder = new MenuOptionBuilder<Link>(new MenuOptionBean()){};
        <.... snip ....>
    }
}
```

I would prefer not to have to add additional base classes like `AbstractSimpleLinkedMenu`, so is there something I have missed or done incorrectly here? I thought that the anonymous inner class for the abstract builder would know the runtime type, expect that it doesn't if the builder is declared with a generic parameter. The runtime type is specified by the concrete menu `class`, `SimpleMenu`, but it doesn't seem to filter through to the `abstract` builder class for menu options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how the `TypeToken` *"hack"* works. It uses [`Class#getGenericSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--) (or `getGenericSuperInterface`). Its javadoc states

> If the superclass is a parameterized type, the `Type` object returned
>   must accurately reflect **the actual type parameters used in the source
>   code.**

In this case, that is `O`, here

```
public abstract class AbstractMenuOptionBuilder<O extends IClickable>
```

You get what is hard coded in the source code. If you hard code `Link` as the type argument, as you do here

```
MenuOptionBuilder<Link> builder = 
    new MenuOptionBuilder<Link>(new MenuOptionBean()) {};
```

then you will get `Link`.

In this case

```
MenuOptionBuilder<O> builder = 
    new MenuOptionBuilder<O>(new MenuOptionBean()){};
```

you've hard coded `O`, so that's what you will get.

Here are some more things I've written on the subject of type tokens:

- [Gson TypeToken with dynamic ArrayList item type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylist-item-type)
- [is it possible to use Gson.fromJson() to get ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271779/is-it-possible-to-use-gson-fromjson-to-get-arraylistarrayliststring)

Comment: Actually, that line works. This is the one that does not:  `MenuOptionBuilder<O> builder = new MenuOptionBuilder<O>(new MenuOptionBean()){};`. When I declare the builder with a concrete type like `Link`, the type token in its underlying `abstract` base `class` _can_ resolve the runtime type to `Link`. I cannot, however, declare it with a generic type parameter like `O` and rely on type token to resolve the runtime type which is specified by the conrete menu `class` extending `AbstractMenu`.

Comment: @Selena I was unavailable earlier to address your comment. But I've since reread everything and it's exactly as I said. In `MenuOptionBuilder<Link>`, the **source code** uses a concrete type, `Link` as an argument and so that's what will be returned by `getGenericSuperclass`. In `MenuOptionBuilder<O>`, the source code contains the type parameter `O` as a type argument. And so, again, that's what will be returned.

Comment: @Selena But I will edit what I said to clarify, as I see my last sentence is not what I meant.

Comment: I suspected that this was the case. I had held into the hope that TypeToken could derive the runtime type from the concrete menu declaration, but that was clearly not going to happen. I found a way to work around this limitation anyway.