# What does anonymous subclass mean in java?

Tags: java, json

Recently, I'm learning about JSON, using Google's Gson. And I come across a problem. Here is code:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Collection<Data>>(){}.getType();
```

I can't understand what `{}` really mean.So I read source code, and get class description like: Constructs a new type literal. Derives represented class from type parameter... Clients create an empty `anonymous subclass`. `anonymous subclass` really make me confused? Can anyone explain it concretely?

Comment: Are you asking about the type token or about anonymous classes in general?

Comment: Here's an explanation of the type token "hack": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271779/is-it-possible-to-use-gson-fromjson-to-get-arraylistarrayliststring

Answer (score 9):

The `{}` is the body of an anonymous class.

If you wanted to make it more readable, this is what it could look like:

```
class MyTypeToken extends TypeToken<Collection<Data>> { }
TypeToken<Collection<Data>> tcd = new MyTypeToken();
Type type = tcd.getType();
```

Here is a breakdown of the more succinct shorthand you have used:

```
Type type =
    new TypeToken<Collection<Data>>() { // this will initialise an anonymous object
        /* in here you can override methods and add your own if you need to */

    }   /* this ends the initialisation of the object. 
           At this point the anonymous class is created and initialised. */

    .getType(); // here you call a method on the object
```

I prefer using this:

```
TypeToken<Collection<Data>> tt = new TypeToken<Collection<Data>>(){ };
Type type = tt.getType();
```

---

One more thing I want to mention is that anonymous classes do not have the same class type as other anonymous classes which inherit from the same parent.

So if you have the following:

```
TypeToken<Collection<Data>> tt1 = new TypeToken<Collection<Data>>(){ };
TypeToken<Collection<Data>> tt2 = new TypeToken<Collection<Data>>(){ };
```

`tt1.getClass() == tt2.getClass()` will **never** be true.

Comment: Your answer really helps me. Thx.